# How to find Windows 7 version on CD

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have what should be a Windows 7 full version on CD, and is installed on the PC that I bought used. 
I know how to get the product ID from System in control panel from a search on this similar subject.

How can I know if the Windows 7 CD is full version or OEM?

Thanks

Comment: Check the label of the disk. It will either say OEM or retail.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

- Hit the start menu
- Right-click "Computer" and choose "Properties"
- Scroll down to the bottom, and look for something that says "Product key"
- If it says OEM in it like this image, it is OEM. If it had 3 numbers in that slot, it's a full key.

[image]

Comment: Is that going to involve him Installing Windows first?  If so, worth mentioning that 'cos it's a very very inefficient solution.  And does he not have to enter the OEM number(is it on the CD)?  'cos if he doesn't have to enter the OEM, then it's probably in a file on the CD. And if he does have to enter it, then he'd know the info

Comment: @barlop He's saying that he has bought a used PC and wants to check if the CD key (Product ID) is OEM.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know OEM would be in the product key.

Comment: @user3433705 No problem. By the way, if this worked for you, click the checkmark under my answer to mark it as solved.